# Error while compiling my solidity contact

Tags: solidity, contract-development, javascript

Below is the contact code. This is basically a lottery contract.

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.8.10;

contract Lottery {
    address public manager;
    address[] public players;

    constructor() public {
        manager = msg.sender;
    }

    function enter() public payable {
        require(msg.value > .01 ether);

        players.push(msg.sender);
    }

    function random() private view returns (uint) {
        return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty,block.timestamp,players)));

    }

    function pickWinner() public restricted {
        uint index = random() % players.length;
        payable(players[index]).transfer(address(this).balance);
        players = new address[](0);
    }

    modifier restricted() {
        require(msg.sender == manager);
        _;
    }

    function getPlayers() public view returns (address payable[] memory) {
        return players;
    }
}
```

On the last line `return players`, I am getting this `ERROR: Return argument type address[] storage ref is not implicitly convertible to expected type (type of first return variable) address payable[] memory.`

**What am I missing ??**

Answer (score 0):

You could change your `getPlayers()` function to the following:

```
    function getPlayers() public view returns (address[] memory) {
        return players;
    }
```

From solidity 0.8.0 onwards you dont need to explicitly define things as payable. You can just wrap addresses in payable when you need it. For example:

```
    function test() public payable {
        address player1 = getPlayers()[0];
        payable(player1).transfer(msg.value);
    }
```